# How to count the charaters in a string in if condition

Tags: java

We have been trying to limit the number of characters in first name, like the first name should not be more than 4.

And also, we need to make sure that the salary should be exactly 100000.

Could anyone please help us to sort this out?

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
public class ReadXml_File {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
        File hxmlfile = new File("C:\\myjava\\staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuild = dbFact.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuild.parse(hxmlfile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root Element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        for(int temp = 0;temp<nList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\n Current Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Staff id :" + eElement.getAttribute("id"));             
                System.out.println("First Name :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Last Name :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Nick Name :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());                     
            }   
        }
        }
        if (count.id    )
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>Harikrishnan</firstname>
        <lastname>S R</lastname>
        <nickname>Hari</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>Ashwin</firstname>
        <lastname>Suma</lastname>
        <nickname>Ashwin</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="3001">
        <firstname>Ebin</firstname>
        <lastname>Mathew</lastname>
        <nickname>Ebin</nickname>
        <salary>300000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Comment: I don't see any code below as you wrote.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code. Add it as text to your post.

Comment: @RalfRenz, 

Hi Ralf, We are trying to parse the attached XML  in java and then do some validation. Could you please help?

Comment: What is the desired result if the name is longer than 4 chars? An error or shut it just be cut off? Same goes for the salary? What should happen if it is != 100000?

Comment: @JanGassen, 

It should print back an error like, Validation failed-count is more than 4.

Comment: @JanGassen, 

It should print back an error like, Validation failed-count is more than 4.

-What should happen if it is != 100000? 
again, it should print back values doesn't match.

Thanks Jan, for you kind time

Comment: This `if (count.id    )` looks like a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just print out the valid lines, modify your loop content like this:

```
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
String firstName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
// You might want to catch NumberFormatException here if input is not a valid integer
int salary = Integer.parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

if (firstName.length() > 4) {
  System.err.println("Validation failed-count is more than 4");
} else if (salary != 100000) {
  System.err.println("Validation failed-salary is not 100000");
} else {
  System.out.println("Staff id :" + eElement.getAttribute("id"));             
  System.out.println("First Name :" + firstName);
  System.out.println("Last Name :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
  System.out.println("Nick Name :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
  System.out.println("Salary : " + salary);             
}
```

This will check if the length of the first name is longer than 4 characters or the salary is not equal to 100000 and print a respective error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jan

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Why not mark it as answer then ;)